# No records in Mysql.func table even though there are stored functions in server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, stored-procedures, functions

When i am creating a user defined function in one of my mysql server, it's not creating any row in mysql.func table . Even though i have multiple functions in my mysql server , this table is empty . Can someone explain me why its not getting logged . it should create row like mysql.proc table right whenever we create any stored procedure. I am using mysql 5.5.40. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All stored procedures and stored functions, whose code is written in the MySQL Stored Procedure Language, reside in `mysql.proc`.

You can see how many of each with this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) rowcount,type
FROM mysql.proc GROUP BY type;
```

The only time I have ever seen `mysql.func` is in context with `AGGREGATE` functions:

According to [MySQL Documentation on `CREATE FUNCTION Syntax for User-Defined Functions`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html)

> An AGGREGATE function works exactly like a native MySQL aggregate (summary) function such as SUM or COUNT(). For AGGREGATE to work, your mysql.func table must contain a type column. If your mysql.func table does not have this column, you should run the [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html) program to create it (see [Section 4.4.7, “mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html)).

My guess is that `mysql.func` stores `AGGREGATE` functions and not regular functions. Evidently, you would create some UDF in C/C++ and register it in `mysql.func` using the `CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION` syntax.

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo. But in the above link it is mentioned like "To create a function, you must have the INSERT privilege for the mysql database. This is necessary because CREATE FUNCTION adds a row to the mysql.func system table that records the function's name, type, and shared library name. If you do not have this table, you should run the mysql_upgrade command to create it. See Section 4.4.7, “mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables”. "..it's little bit confusing actually. Please let me know if i am missing any point here.

Comment: The point is this: 1) If you wrote the stored function using MySQL Stored Procedure Language, it goes into `mysql.proc` using `CREATE FUNCTION`. 2) If you wrote the stored function in C/C++ and placed that compiled code in some `.so` file, you must use `CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION ... SONAME ...` and the function name goes into `mysql.func`.